# How to find cumulative sum between two dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery, window-functions

How to find cumulative sum between two dates taking into account the previous state?

Putting `WHERE` condition

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-02-19 12:00:00'AND '2021-02-21 12:00:00';
```

doesn't do the job because the sum starts from the first condition's date, and not from the first record. I would like to select only part of the whole query (between two dates), but to calculate cumulative sum from the first (initial) state.

I prepared [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b7d43184674e0c836a800f3db331654)

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `payment` double NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `date`, `payment`) VALUES
(1, '2021-02-16 12:00:00', 100),
(2, '2021-02-17 12:00:00', 200),
(3, '2021-02-18 12:00:00', 300),
(4, '2021-02-19 12:00:00', 400),
(5, '2021-02-20 12:00:00', 500),
(6, '2021-02-21 12:00:00', 600),
(7, '2021-02-22 12:00:00', 700);
 version();
```

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date, 
payment, SUM(payment) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS balance 
FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-02-19 12:00:00'AND '2021-02-21 12:00:00';
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: 1000, 1500, 2100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must filter the table after you get the cumulative sums:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(date) AS date, 
         payment, 
         SUM(payment) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS balance 
  FROM table1
) t 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-02-19'AND '2021-02-21';
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(date) AS date, 
         payment, 
         SUM(payment) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS balance 
  FROM table1
  WHERE DATE(date) <= '2021-02-21'
) t 
WHERE date >= '2021-02-19';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=222af019a4e4585f6bc4089c3e20472c).
Results:

| date | payment | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-19 | 400 | 1000 |
| 2021-02-20 | 500 | 1500 |
| 2021-02-21 | 600 | 2100 |